# Mapping Windows key in Gvim

Tags: xubuntu, vim, gvim

How do I map the Windows key in Gvim? I've tried referencing it as `T` as suggested [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Mapping_keys_in_Vim_-_Tutorial_%28Part_2%29) and it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/327415/can-windows-key-be-mapped-in-vim), see if it helps.

Comment: I don't know exactly but you should maybe think about twice mapping the Windows key, because many Desktop environments use it as default. Also tiling window managers like i3wm.